# Elastic Beanstalk | CodePipeline will not deploy .war file correctly

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, war, aws-codepipeline

I'm having a problem with my .war file deployment through CodePipeline (using CodeBuild) to my Elastic Beanstalk environment. After a successful pipeline deployment, it throws a 404 error (see picture).

However, when I upload the .war file from my project code directly into my Elastic Beanstalk environment, it works just fine.

Ideally, I want to just be able to run the CodePipeline to update the versioning.

My CodeBuild (buildspec) -

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto11

  build:
    commands:
      - ls -la
      - cd prod/
      - mvn clean
      - mvn install
  # post_build:
  #   commands:
artifacts:
  files:
  - backend/target/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
  # name: artifact 
  base-directory: prod/
```

404 Error -

[image: Error picture]

I've tried this as well and it still gives me a 404 error

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto11

  build:
    commands:
      - ls -la
      - cd prod/
      - mvn clean
      - mvn install
post_build:
    commands:
      - mv backend/target/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war ROOT.war
artifacts:
  files:
      - ROOT.war
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Elastic Beanstalk expects to find and run a `ROOT.war` at root directory.

> ROOT.war runs at myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com. In a single WAR source
> bundle, the application always runs at the root path.
> ([Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html#java-tomcat-options))

You have two options to resolve this

1. Make sure that your artifact is named ROOT.war and is found at root level (in contrary to `backend/target/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`)
2. Use the post_build phase in your CodePipeline to rename and move the file adequately (the easier option).

Option 2 approach:

```
post_build:
    commands:
      - mv backend/target/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war ROOT.war
```

Comment: I've tried to that exact same thing (second option) and it still hasn't worked. I still receive a 404 error

Comment: Did you change the files in the `artifacts` section as well? That should have been the old path that you had in your initial question.

Comment: If you look above, I've added the setup I tried there. I think that is what I was supposed to do, no?

Comment: I believe you also changed the artifacts section. Better revert that back to `prod/backend/target/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war` and also add the `prod` directory above in the post_build command, please.